# Retrieve elements from a 3D tensor with a 2D index tensor

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am playing around with GPT2 and I have 2 tensors:

**O**: An output tensor of shaped (B, S-1, V) where B is the batch size S is the the number of timestep and V is the vocabulary size. This is the output of a generative model and is softmaxed along the 2nd dimension.

**L**: A 2D tensor shaped (B, S-1) where each element is the index of the correct token for each timestep for each sample. This is basically the labels.

I want to extract the predicted probability of the corresponding correct token from tensor **O** based on tensor **L** such that I will end up with a 2D tensor shaped (B, S). Is there an efficient way of doing this apart from using loops?

Comment: Can you add sample tensors and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I based my answer on [this Medium article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/understanding-indexing-with-pytorch-gather-33717a84ebc4).
Essentially, your answer lies in `torch.gather`, assuming that both of your tensors are just regular `torch.Tensor`s (or can be converted to one).

```py
import torch

# Specify some arbitrary dimensions for now
B = 3
V = 6
S = 4

# Make example reproducible
torch.manual_seed(42)

# L necessarily has to be a torch.LongTensor, otherwise indexing will fail.
L = torch.randint(0, V, size=[B, S])

O = torch.rand([B, S, V])

# Now collect the results. L needs to have similar dimension,
# except in the axis you want to collect along.
X = torch.gather(O, dim=2, index=L.unsqueeze(dim=2))

# Make sure X has no "unnecessary" dimension
X = X.squeeze(dim=2)
```

It is a bit difficult to see whether this produces the exact correct results, which is why I included a random seed which makes the example deterministic in the result, and you an easily verify that it gets you the desired results. However, for clarification, one could also use a lower-dimensional tensor, for which this becomes clearer what exactly `torch.gather` does.

Note that `torch.gather` also allows you to index multiple indexes in the same row theoretically. Meaning if you instead got a multiclass example for which multiple values are correct, you could similarly use a tensor `L` of shape `[B, S, number_of_correct_samples]`.